# How to install TWebBrowser in Delphi 2010

Tags: delphi, installation, delphi-2010, twebbrowser

Is there any way of installing TWebBrowser in Delphi 2010 directly without having to install the Web Development Controls?

If I select the Web Development Controls option on the Delphi 2010 setup, TWebBrowser is installed. But this "package" is over 200 MB and I only need TWebBrowser.

Any way of installing TWebBrowser directly on Delphi 2010 Pro?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can also import TWebBrowser as an ActiveX control directly:

1. Goto the "*Component*" Menu with Delphi and select "*Import Component*"
2. Select "*Import ActiveX Control*" from the resulting Dialog
3. Use the search filter to find the "*Microsoft Internet Controls*" and press next
4. Choose which palette you would like them to be placed in.

You can then choose where you'd like the imported package to be placed and after you select the Install (and not create unit) option then you'll be ready to use it.